# BATCH - RPS - Rock, Paper, Scissors - Keep failing after a few rounds

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, goto

I have been trying to make a rock, paper, scissors game in batch. So far, the script runs and I can make it play against itself or to play against me (I need to change the B var from /A and random number to /P and have user input).

The thing is that after a few (different amount every time) rounds, the script crash and I do not have time to read the last line of text (which would help me find the error). I have tried with ECHO ON and OFF, I also tried to run 'RPS.bat >> log.txt' from a different DOS window (with the right directory chosen). That did log everything until it crashed, and did not get the last line either.

I have been looking through it several times, but I cant find the error... :(

I made the same game in PHP with currently no errors... (it is a totally different language, I know)

So here is my script:

```
@ECHO OFF
:TOP
SET /A AWON=0
SET /A BWON=0
SET /A NWON=0

:GAME
SET /A A=%RANDOM% %% 3 + 1
SET /P B=Number from 1 to 3

IF %A% EQU 1 (
    GOTO A1
) ELSE IF %A% EQU 2 (
GOTO A2
) ELSE IF %A% EQU 3 (
GOTO A3
) ELSE (
GOTO GAME
)

:A1
IF %B% EQU 1 (
GOTO DRAW
) ELSE IF %B% EQU 2 (
GOTO BWIN
) ELSE IF %B% EQU 3 (
GOTO AWIN
) ELSE (
    GOTO GAME
)

:A2
IF %B% EQU 1 (
    GOTO ARAW
) ELSE IF %B% EQU 2 (
    GOTO DRAW
) ELSE IF %B% EQU 3 (
    GOTO BWIN
) ELSE (
    GOTO GAME
)

:A3
IF %B% EQU 1 (
    GOTO BWIN
) ELSE IF %B% EQU 2 (
    GOTO AWIN
) ELSE IF %B% EQU 3 (
    GOTO DRAW
) ELSE (
    GOTO GAME
)

:AWIN
SET /A AWON=%AWON% + 1
ECHO -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ECHO A won this round!
ECHO ---
ECHO A won: %AWON%
ECHO B won: %BWON%
ECHO Draw: %NWON%
PAUSE
GOTO GAME

:BWIN
SET /A BWON=%BWON% + 1
ECHO -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ECHO B won this round!
ECHO ---
ECHO A won: %AWON%
ECHO B won: %BWON%
ECHO Draw: %NWON%
PAUSE
GOTO GAME

:DRAW
SET /A NWON=%NWON% + 1
ECHO -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ECHO This round was a draw!
ECHO ---
ECHO A won: %AWON%
ECHO B won: %BWON%
ECHO Draw: %NWON%
PAUSE
GOTO GAME
```

Thanks to Gray for helping me out with my stupid mistake ^^

Also thanks for the script, but if I am not missing something here, it is not *quite* correct.

```
@ECHO OFF
:GAME
SET /P A=A: 
SET /P B=B: 
SET /A WINNER=(%A%-%B%) %% 3
ECHO %A% - %B% = %WINNER%
IF %WINNER% EQU 1 (
    echo A WON! 
) ELSE (
IF %WINNER% EQU 0 (
    echo DRAW!
) ELSE (
    echo B WON!
))
PAUSE
GOTO GAME
```

Run that script (a 'shortened' version of Gray's script). Use the variables like as in my 'table', you can see that by choosing 1 (rock), A is not able to win (A=1 vs B=3 should be: A WON). Do you have any idea on how to fix this? I guess a 'hard-coded?' solution when A=1 and B=3 would be best? (I mean that when those are the values, the 'normal' script does not apply, but a special code gives the result instead).

In my table, if the last sign is '+', then the script gives the correct answer, if the last sign is a '-', then the script gives an incorrect answer.

```
ITEM     VALUE

ROCK     1
PAPER    2
SCISSORS 3

A - B = WINNER

1 - 1 =  0 DRAW  +
1 - 2 = -1 B WON +
1 - 3 = -2 A WON -
2 - 1 =  1 A WON +
2 - 2 =  0 DRAW  +
2 - 3 = -1 B WON +
3 - 1 =  2 B WON +
3 - 2 =  1 A WON +
3 - 3 =  0 DRAW  +
```

Also, if you have any tips on how to keep the script more tidy and use less lines code to do the same job, I would gladly listen!

Thanks in advance! - Espen

Comment: As far as seeing the error, did you try executing it from a command window rather than just running the file? Alternatively, you can try redirecting stderr to a file as well with this: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did not know you could run the script like that (only how to start them as if I clicked on them). When the script stopped while running it from the DOS window, the last line was: The system cannot find the batch label specified - ARAW. I seached my script for ARAW, it was a misspelling of AWIN! If A was 2and B was 1 the error occurd. I fixed it and ran the scipt 300 rounds (bot played both A and B) and with no error! Thaks!

Comment: Should I remove this qestion, or should it just stay as-is?

Comment: Ha, well, I actually noticed that when I ran it and made an answer to the question. You can just mark my answer as correct if you want. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error likely says:

> The system cannot find the batch label specified - ARAW

This is because you have `GOTO ARAW` in your `A2` label, when it looks like you meant to do `GOTO AWIN`

Bonus: as a more "clever" way of determining the winner (can surely be improved more)

```
@echo off

rem rock:1; paper:2; scissors:3
:GAME
SET /A CPU=%RANDOM% %% 3 + 1
SET /P PLAYER=Number from 1 to 3
cls
echo %CPU% vs %PLAYER%

rem set /A WINNER=(%CPU%-%PLAYER%) %% 3 //this does not work with batch - my mistake
SET /A WINNER=(%CPU% - %PLAYER% + 3) %% 3

IF %WINNER% EQU 1 (
   echo CPU WON! 
) ELSE (
IF %WINNER% EQU 0 (
   echo DRAW!
) ELSE (
   echo YOU WON!
))

GOTO GAME
```

And finally, here is one that prints "rock", "paper", and "scissors" to make it a little more... fun

```
@echo off

rem rock:1; paper:2; scissors:3
:GAME
SET /A CPU=%RANDOM% %% 3 + 1
SET /P PLAYER=Number from 1 to 3
goto CPUTYPE
:TYPE1
goto PLAYERTYPE
:TYPE2
cls
echo CPU:%CPUT% vs YOU:%PLAYERT%

rem set /A WINNER=(%CPU%-%PLAYER%) %% 3 //this does not work with batch - my mistake
SET /A WINNER=(%CPU% - %PLAYER% + 3) %% 3
IF %WINNER% EQU 1 (
    echo CPU WON! 
) ELSE (
IF %WINNER% EQU 0 (
    echo DRAW!
) ELSE (
    echo YOU WON!
))

GOTO GAME

:CPUTYPE
    IF %CPU% EQU 1 (
        SET CPUT="ROCK" 
    ) ELSE (
    IF %CPU% EQU 2 (
        SET CPUT="PAPER" 
    ) ELSE (
        SET CPUT="SCISSORS" 
    ))
    GOTO TYPE1

:PLAYERTYPE
    IF %PLAYER% EQU 1 (
        SET PLAYERT="ROCK" 
    ) ELSE (
    IF %PLAYER% EQU 2 (
        SET PLAYERT="PAPER" 
    ) ELSE (
        SET PLAYERT="SCISSORS" 
    ))
    GOTO TYPE2
```

Updated version based on asker's PvP version (fixed modul

```
@ECHO OFF
:GAME
SET /P A=A: 
SET /P B=B: 
SET /A WINNER=(%A% - %B% + 3) %% 3
ECHO W= %WINNER%
IF %WINNER% EQU 1 (
    echo A WON! 
) ELSE (
IF %WINNER% EQU 0 (
    echo DRAW!
) ELSE (
    echo B WON!
))
PAUSE
GOTO GAME
```

### Explanation of `SET /A WINNER=(%CPU% - %PLAYER% + 3) %% 3`:

2 beats 1, 3 beats 2, and 1 beats 3. If you draw it out, it is kind of circular. We use the `%` or modulus operator to do that. The modulus operator basically gives you the remainder if you had divided by that number using integer division.

Here are 1 through 6 mod 3, with the answer in bold.

1 / 3 = 0 rem **1**

2 / 3 = 0 rem **2**

3 / 3 = 1 rem **0**

4 / 3 = 1 rem **1**

5 / 3 = 1 rem **2**

6 / 3 = 2 rem **0**

Notice how the result is always < 3 and > 0? We exploit this mechanic to mimic the circular behavior of rock paper scissors. You also may have noticed I didn't do the +3 in those examples. The +3 was added because the way Microsoft chose to implement modulus, it does weird things when you have a negative number (that was how we fixed the bug you caught). I had assumed it used a modulus like I was used to where the sign didn't change the outcome. Basically, it just shifts the operation up 3 so that it is never negative. You can read more about this kind of thing here: [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). I like examples, so here is something that may help.

#### Ties:

> 1v1 -> (1 - 1 + 3) % 3 -> 3 % 3 -> 1 rem **0**
>
> 2v2 -> (2 - 2 + 3) % 3 -> 3 % 3 -> 1 rem **0**
>
> 3v3 -> (3 - 3 + 3) % 3 -> 3 % 3 -> 1 rem **0**

#### player 1 win

> 1v3 -> (1 - 3 + 3) % 3 -> 1 % 3 -> 0 rem **1**
>
> 2v1 -> (2 - 1 + 3) % 3 -> 4 % 3 -> 1 rem **1**
>
> 3v2 -> (3 - 2 + 3) % 3 -> 4 % 3 -> 1 rem **1**

#### player 2 win

> 1v2 -> (1 - 2 + 3) % 3 -> 2 % 3 -> 0 rem **2**
>
> 2v3 -> (2 - 3 + 3) % 3 -> 2 % 3 -> 0 rem **2**
>
> 3v1 -> (3 - 1 + 3) % 3 -> 5 % 3 -> 1 rem **2**

The pattern here is that all of the remainders (results of the modulus operator) all match up. How convenient! Now we can just match that case to an if-statement, and we know who won every game.

Comment: @Espen No problem, I also updated my answer with a different way of calculating the winner... just for fun.

Comment: Look at the bottom of my question (I don't know how to post multi-line code in comments). I have tried your script, but found one error. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Espen I have fixed the bug you caught - let me know if there are any more issues.

Comment: Perfect! Very much appreciated that you take time to answer so thoughtfully :)

Comment: @Gary I am sorry, but how does the `%% 3` in `SET /A WINNER=(%A% - %B% + 3) %% 3` work/what is it? I am not sure how to find the answer. I have tried to use it on other variables and so on but still don't get it.

Comment: @Espen Hey, no problem. I updated my answer to include an explanation at the bottom. Let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for this detailed explanation! I do understand the concept and I will be able to recreate this formula when I update my PHP version :)